# apply the weight data to the MCA function

Tags: r, factominer, mca

I have a data set of 25 qualitative variables and the 26th variable corresponds to the weight assigned to each individual.

I used the `MCA` function from the `FactoMiner` package, and to take into account the weighting I added the option `row.w`. here is my code :

```
res.mca <- MCA(Vague5_ACM[,-26],
              row.w = Vague5_ACM[,26],
              quali.sup = 1:2,
              graph=T)
```

however, adding the `row. w` option gives me an error message :

Error `in MCA(Vague5_ACM[, -26], row.w = Vague5_ACM[, 26], quali.sup = 1:2,  :  length of vector row.w should be the number of active rows`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution :

in my data vector with the weights, an individual had a weight = 0. so, I deleted it from my data, and and I kept only the active observations != 0.